# How to extract Date from the filename and add column while reading thorough Pandas DF in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

I have set of files in my folder and wants to capture the date in the file name and add it to a column while reading through Pandas Data Frame.

I have filenames like- 
 X_04_24_2018.txt
 Y_04_25_2018.txt
 Z_04_26_2018.txt

Lets say the file has 2 columns with the sample content in it, I would need a data frame with the below format. Appreciate you help on this.

```
Col1    Col2    Date        File
XXX     ABC     4/24/2018   X
YYY     BCA     4/25/2018   Y
ZZZ     CBA     4/26/2018   Z
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a a dictionary comprehension with `os.path` to extract the relevant details from a list of filenames.

Then use another dictionary comprehension to read files, using `pd.DataFrame.assign` to assign the relevant columns.

```
from os import path
import pandas as pd

files = ['X_04_24_2018.txt', 'Y_04_25_2018.txt', 'Z_04_26_2018.txt']

att = {files[idx]: [i[0][:-11], i[0][-10:].replace('_', '/')]
                   for idx, i in enumerate(map(path.splitext, files))}

dfs = {f: pd.read_csv(f).assign(Date=att[f][1], File=att[f[0]]) for f in files}
```